# add nodes and edges through loop in cytoscape arbor layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js, arbor.js

I want to add more than 10 nodes in arbor.js layout.This code adds nodes  and edges in arbor layout for cytoscape

```
 elements: {

            nodes: [
                { data : { id: b[0], faveBorderColor: "#AAAAAA", name: b[0], faveColor: "#EEB211", faveFontColor: "#ffffff" ,'link':'http://www.yahoo.com'} },
                { data : { id: a[0], name: a[0], faveColor: "#21526a", faveFontColor: "#fff"} },
                { data : { id: a[1], name: a[1], faveColor: "#21526a", faveFontColor: "#fff"} },
                { data : { id: a[2], name: a[2], faveColor: "#21526a", faveFontColor: "#fff"} },
                { data : { id: a[3], name: a[3], faveColor: "#21526a", faveFontColor: "#fff"} },
                { data : { id: a[4], name: a[4], faveColor: "#21526a", faveFontColor: "#fff"} }
            ], //end "nodes"

            edges: [
                { data : { target: a[0], source : b[0] } },
                { data : { target: a[1], source : b[0]} },
                { data : { target: a[2], source : b[0]} },
                { data : { target: a[3], source : b[0]} },
                { data : { target: a[4], source : b[0]} }
            ]//end "edges"
        },//end "elements"
```

Now i have 100s of nodes to be added. a[] and b[] are arrays which gets data dynamically through mysql. Is there any chance to loop through nodes, so that all the data can be added dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add elements to the graph in a loop with [cy.add()](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/graph-manipulation/cy.add):

```
// assuming your graph object is available as 'cy' e.g. by
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy')
});

a = your array
b = the other array

for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {

    var name = a[i]

    cy.add([
        {group: "nodes", data: {id: name, ... }},
        { group: "edges", data: { id: a[i]+b[0], source: a[i], target: b[0]},...}
    ])
};
```

This will add all nodes from array `a` and add an edge to the first element of `b`. Nodes are identified by their id and nodes with existing ids are not added again. How you figure out which nodes from `a` and `b` are connected depends on your data structure of course.

You can [rerun the layout with](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/visuals/cy.layout):

```
cy.layout( ... );
```

Comment: Note it's much more performant to have one call to `cy.add()` with all of the elements at once.  Instead of calling `cy.add()` repeatedly, you could build a to-add elements array and then call `cy.add( toAddEles )` after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the reply.It pushed me in a right direction. I performed this with simple loops as I had to change my whole layout to implement this.

```
var demoNodes = [];
var demoEdges = [];

demoNodes.push({

    data: {
        id: b[0],
        name:b[0]
    }
});

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    demoNodes.push({

        data: {
            id: a[i],
            name:a[i]
        }
    });
}



for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    demoEdges.push({
        data: {
            source: b[0],
            target: a[i]

        }
    });
}
```

and put these values in elements

```
elements: {
            nodes: demoNodes,
            edges: demoEdges
        },
```

It worked out pretty well.

Comment: worked like a carm, I want to add some animation and some elasticity in the edges and node. any idea how to achieve that ?